# Define Pins For Use By a Library xc8

Tags: pic, mplabx, xc8

I've got some code i'd like to use in multiple projects so i'd like to put it into a library

The library will use no special features of the chip and whichever two pins it uses to do its job only have to be general I/O

As I plan to use this for multiple projects, these projects will have to specify which pins these two pins are on a project-by-project basis

My question is how I can set up my library and code in each project so that I can define which pins I want to use within each project - independent of the library.

Using XC8 compiler for PIC10s and 16s

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if that changed recently, but a year ago or two I contacted Microchip technical support who confirmed that XC8 doesn't support libraries as such.

What you can do is have the C file in a "shared" folder and include it in the various projects.

The pins can be:

- defined by macros (#define) either in compiler options, or in a header of a predefined name e.g. "hardwareconfig.h" which your module would include and the projects supply;
- supplied at initialization by pointers to LAT/PORT registers and masks of the bits;
- your module could declare functions for the low level pin handling, call those, and the various projects would implement them as they see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Define a strict that supports bits. Cast that strict to your variables and you have addressable bits.

Or use those ore defined in thee header file.

edit: to just expand a little bit of what I said earlier, here is an example of how this could be done on an 8-pin port.

```
//define a bit-addresable byte
typedef struct {
    uint8_t B0:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B1:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B2:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B3:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B4:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B5:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B6:1;                           //bit definitions
    uint8_t B7:1;                           //bit definitions
} B8_TypeDef;

//global variables
#define LED0            (((B8_TypeDef *)&PORTB)->B0)    //led0 on PORTB.0

//in your main loop
    while (1) {
        //flip LED0/PORTB.0
        LED0 = 1;                           //set LED0/PORTB.0
        LED0 = 0;                           //clear LED0 / PORTB.0
```

if you go through the canned header file, you will find an identical approach, except that each typedef has a different name.

here is how it goes in simulation:
[image]

The same concept can be done on variables, or 16/32-bit types, to the extend that the compiler support bit types.